# GA4 - Configure GTM Server to work with stape.io and Site kit

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-tag-manager-server-side

I have some GA4 properties and to be compliant with the EU GDPR I need to configure a proxy server. I'm trying to use stape.io as proxy service but I'm not sure if I've configured it correctly.

I've followed their official tutorial and I've added a new GTM Server. I've also created a web tag using Site Kit and connected it to the server URL provided from Stape, but no data seems arrive in GA4 Analytics.

How can I proceed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Stape offers Consulting through their agency now if you still need it. I think that's the best advice you can get here with the limited data we have available to help you.